# Can't create folder in external public storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am trying to simply create a subdirectory in the external storage pictures directory, however, I always end up in the lower if condition. (The directory does not exist and mkdir fails creating it).

```
    ...
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "foto_test_app");
    if(!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "External Storage not mounted.");
        return null;
    }

    if(!storageDir.exists() && !storageDir.mkdir())
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created.");
    }
    ...
```

I do have the the line in the Manifest file that reads:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I tested it on two different devices. Both do not have an SDCard installed, but that should not be a concern, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `storageDir.mkdirs()` instead of `storageDir.mkdir()`?

Comment: Yes, that worked equally bad :(

Comment: It sounds dumb but could you try swapping `!storageDir.mkdir()` and `!storageDir.exists()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using Android Marshmallow or above.
You need to make sure that you have granted run-time permission for storage.

This can be done either by setting it explicitly in the settings of your android device or asking for the permission during run time.

You can check below link how run time permission works

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction and this fixed it. I activated the 'storage' permission in the settings of my tablet and after that, I was able to create the desired folder. This may just be a fast development hack but worked for the time being. Thank you very much for your help. However I was not using Android Marshmallow but Version 7.0, so if you could change your answer to say "Android Marshmallow or above", that would help many people.